# How to convert datatable column type to perform filter

Tags: c#, filter, datatable

So i'm trying to filter my data with `BindingSource` from my `datagridview`
but **my Column (Balance and Inactive Days)** type is `string` also have `Null value` and i'm trying to use comparison operators `<=, >=`

but error shown `System.Data.EvaluateException: 'Cannot perform '>=' operation on System.String and System.Int32.'`

i've tried to change valueType of my datagridview,
`dgv.Columns["Balance"].ValueType = typeof(Decimal); //it doesnt work`

and tried to clone my datatable and set new type for my cloned datatable

```
DataTable dtCloned = dt.Clone();
dtCloned.Columns["Balance"].DataType = typeof(Decimal);
dtCloned.Columns["Inactive Days"].DataType = typeof(Int32);
foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
{
    dtCloned.ImportRow(row);
}

// error shown
System.ArgumentException: 'Input string was not in a correct format.Couldn't store <> in Debit Inactive Days Column.  Expected type is Int32.'
```

Here is my filter code:

```
public void dgv_tabPage_content(DataGridView dgv, TabPage tabpage)
{
   BindingSource bs = new BindingSource();
   bs.DataSource = dgv.DataSource;

   string filter_DD1 = "[Acct Type] LIKE '%DD%' AND [Balance] <= 6000.00 AND [Inactive Days] >= 5";
   string filter_DD2 = "[Acct Type] LIKE '%DD%' AND [Balance] >= 6000.00 AND [Inactive Days] >= 3";

   bs.Filter = string.Format("{1} OR {2}", filter_DD1, filter_DD2);
   dgv.DataSource = bs;
}
```

How can i filter my string typed column with null value with comparison operators?

Answer (score 0):

I'M not sure if that what you meant, but why not use `where is not null` and then your filter closure.

```
string filter = string.Format("[Task] is not null and LIKE '%{0}%'", tabpage.Text);
```

Comment: i tried it on `filter_DD1` by adding [Balance] IS NOT NULL AND [Balance] <= 6000.00 AND [Inactive Days] IS NOT NULL AND [Inactive Days] >= 10";` but it shows `System.Data.EvaluateException: 'Cannot perform '>=' operation on System.String and System.Int32.'`

Comment: because you are triting to compare string to int. What is the type of balance? It should be decimal or int

Comment: `Balance` should be decimal, but it is string, `Inactive Days` should be int, but it is string

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean to convert the type in the filter expression.
If this is what you mean, you can use the Convert function of the filter Expression: Convert(expression, type)

```
string filter_DD1 = "[Acct Type] LIKE '%DD%' AND Convert([Balance], System.Decimal) <= 6000.00 AND [Inactive Days] >= 5";
```

For more Info click [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datacolumn.expression?view=net-5.0)